# Using delimited text layer to keep only those polygons and records of a shapefile which match a column in the delimited text layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, filter

What I want to do is trim the shapefile so that only those records and associated shapes that match the same values in a column in the delimited text layer (which in my case is a CSV) are kept in a new shapefile file.

Comment: Suggest you look at a [join](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-field-value).

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that you have a polygon vector layer named "polygons", with a column named "name".
Assuming also that you have a delimited text layer named "csv", also with a column named "name".

You can [Create a Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers), with the rows of the "polygons" layer that have the same value in the "name" column as any row (in the "name" column too) of the "csv" layer, with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  p.* 
FROM 
  polygons AS p 
  INER JOIN
    csv AS c 
    ON
      p.name = c.name
```

Then, you can export the virtual layer to a shapefile.

Replace `polygons`, `csv` and `name` with the name of your layers and common field.
Note that the data type must be the same for both columns.